# AspComet with asp.net (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, comet

**EDIT 1:**

Can someone please help me create a very very simplistic sample page as the chat page included is too coomplete.  something as simple as detecting a change in the database and displaying the word "change" on screen in realtime for any client connected.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have just discovered aspcomet and can't figure out how to use it.

Using the info from the following link

> https://github.com/nmosafi/aspComet/blob/master/README.md

I downloaded a single dll file, and added it to the bin directory of my root folder.  I added the relievant line into the web.config file:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="POST" path="comet.axd" validate="false" type="AspComet.CometHttpHandler, AspComet"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

and I tried creating a global.asax file into which I added in the line mentioned in the link above, but it does not seem to like the word "Setup" in the line Setup.AspComet.WithTheDefaultServices()

Apparently the name "Setup" is not declared...

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    Setup.AspComet.WithTheDefaultServices()
End Sub
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added an Imports declaration at the top of your Global.asax file?

`Imports AspComet`

Take a look at the chat sample and try running that, you should be able to copy some stuff from there to get you set up, although that is C# and you are VB they're quite similar.

Comment: Thanks, I will not be able to try this until sometime next week.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.  Do you have a very very basic example for me to get started, your chat example is too complex for me.  When I say a simple example, How would I simply display a message on all clients screen by pressing a button for example.

Comment: The chat sample started off quite simple but has swiftly grown beyond that! I suggest you read some of the samples on the JQuery or Dojo Comet APIs as they're both supported by aspComet

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check lots of working sample projects in [there](http://pokein.codeplex.com). Most of them written in C# but there is a VB.NET version of Chat sample project.

Actually, once you feel familiar with PokeIn library, it does not matter whether you are using C# or VB.NET.

Comment: The problem with pokein is that it only allows a maximum of 10 concurrent users in the community version.